# Title appears twice in google search

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-search, yoast

My company page title repeats in Google's search engine, and I've tried everything I can think of. Just google 'CO/PLUS' to see the problem. The relevant code of the webpage looks like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="- Where Strategy Meets Creativity">
<meta name="robots" content="noodp">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://coplus.com/">
<link rel="next" href="http://coplus.com/page/2/">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="CO/PLUS - Where Strategy Meets Creativity">
<meta property="og:description" content="- Where Strategy Meets Creativity">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://coplus.com/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="CO/PLUS">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="- Where Strategy Meets Creativity">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="CO/PLUS - Where Strategy Meets Creativity">
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Peter Harket

Comment: Well, your site is lacking **<title>Page Title</title>** in the head section, so Google has no idea what to use.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options for this either you can change title anyone of them or you've to disallow Google bot from google webmaster from the section Robot.txt

Image attached below for help. If you still face any problem then let me know. Great to help.[image: google webmaster]

Comment: Thanks guy for quick replies. It seems that Google was a bit slow to update.